# How do I deploy a VueJS project for production which is using the history mode for routing?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, deployment, configuration, routes

I have created a vueJS website and I have used the history mode for routing in order to get rid of the # in the URL which shows in the default has mode routing. However when I deploy my project to the server after

> npm  run build

it runs fine but when I reload any page or type the url in the browser manual i get a 404 error instead.

I have used the history mode for routing. I am using firebase for the backend. I read the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) on how to fix this however I did not quite understand it.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
mode : 'history',
routes : [
{
path : '/',
name : 'dashboard',
component : 'Dahsboard',
}
]
})
```

Comment: You need to tell your web server to serve the `index.html` file for every request.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that according to the documentation they have given on the website?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to answer in the comment section under your question, so i provide an answer here.

You can find the code that tells the web server to serve the `index.html` file for every routing request [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). Just create a `.htaccess` file and upload it to your server.

In your example above you also need to import your `Dahsboard`-Component if you are using single file components.